# Multiple iterators in a single for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Is it possible to loop over multiple iterators in a single `for`-statement?

```
>>> for i in range(1), range(2):
...  print(i)
...
0
0
1
```

Comment: No, you'd have to e.g. [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) them into a single iterable.

Comment: `range(1) + range(2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing built into the `for` syntax for that; a `for` loop always loops over one iterable. You can *make* [one iterable backed by a bunch of others](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), though:

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.chain(range(1), range(2)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, however you can try alternatives like merging the two ranges to a single list.

```
for i in (range(1)+ range(2)):
  print(i)
```

This should work. range(1) and range(2) are expanded to lists and you can always concatenate them using overloaded '+' operator.

PS:wont work in python3, possibly because range is generated on the fly.

Comment: Not in Python 3.x, it won't.

Comment: "_possibly because range is generated on the fly_" actually, I don't think `range` has a `__add__` method implemented, that's why. Can someone confirm?

Comment: @Coldspeed `dir(range(1))` confirms your suspicion.

Comment: And anyway, even in Python 2.x it is better to use `itertools.chain`, as it avoids creating temporary lists, which might be a memory hog for large ranges.

Comment: @Błotosmętek And so it does. Thanks yo.